# How to hide UIImageView on the cell when it is swiped to delete

Tags: xcode, uitableview, hidden

I am implementing this. But the image is not hiding. What is the proper way?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
PlayerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PlayerCell"];
cell.ratingImageView.hidden= YES;
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the actual cell at the index path, see if the following replacement does the trick:

```
PlayerCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Cheers

Comment: I tried it and it works. But Warning on that line. "incompatible pointer types initializing 'PlayerCell *__strong' with an expression of type 'UITableViewCell *'

Comment: I think you need to add a cast since the return type of that method is UITableViewCell does your PlayerCell inherits from that class? Maybe you need to cast it (PlayerCell*) after the =

Comment: Playercell is a prototypecell class. Don't know how to cast. I'll browse on net. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the cell that was selected using that IndexPath, and then HIDE the imageview from that cell. Im pretty sure the apple tutorials have an example of getting the selected cell.